# Values from one polygon to another

Tags: qgis, polygon, proximity

I am working with QGIS 3.24.2. In the image you can see red buildings (representing a green roof) and the green polygons are gardens.

Every green building has a value to reduce noise pollution in the garden. In the end I need to have a summed up noise reduction value for every garden that touches a building.

I need:

- green roofs that are linked to a garden
- noise reduction values of every green roof assigned to the garden (summed up) [image]

Is there an easy tool available which makes this analysis possible?

Comment: Run `join attributes by nearest`.

Comment: Great! it worked, thank you!